# Union list of lists without duplicates

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have got list of lists. I need to get all combinations of that lists from *2 of N* to *N of N*. 
I'm searching for it with itertools.combinations. After this I got list of lists and I need to combine them without duplicates.

For example I have got array:

```py
a = np.array([[1,4,7],[8,2,5],[8,1,4,6],[8,1,3,5],
              [2,3,4,7],[2,5,6,7],[2,3,4,6,8],[1,3,5,6,7]])
```

I'm searching for all 3 elements combinations:

```py
a2 = list(itertools.combinations(a, 3))

a2[:5]
[([1, 4, 7], [8, 2, 5], [8, 1, 4, 6]),
 ([1, 4, 7], [8, 2, 5], [8, 1, 3, 5]),
 ([1, 4, 7], [8, 2, 5], [2, 3, 4, 7]),
 ([1, 4, 7], [8, 2, 5], [2, 5, 6, 7]),
 ([1, 4, 7], [8, 2, 5], [2, 3, 4, 6, 8])]
```

The length of this array: 56.
I need to combine every list in this array without duplicates.
For exmple for a2[0]  input:

```
([1, 4, 7], [8, 2, 5], [8, 1, 4, 6])
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And so all 56 elements.
I tried to do it with *set*:

```py
arr = list(itertools.combinations(a,3))
for i in arr:
    arrnew[i].append(list(set().union(arr[i][:3])))
```

But I had got error:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-4049ddb4c0be> in <module>()
      3 arrnew = []
      4 for i in arr:
----> 5     for j in arr[i]:
      6         arrnew[i].append(list(set().union(arr[:n])))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I need function for N combinations, that returns new combined array.
But I don't know how to do this because of this error.

Is there way to solve this error or another way to solve this task?

Comment: the value of i in this scenario is a tuple , which is the reason for your error. The problem you are trying to solve is flattening the list. Try to google it up and you'll get your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small function which solves it:

```
def unique_comb(a):
    return list(set(itertools.chain(*a)))
```

For example:

```
unique_comb(([1, 4, 7], [8, 2, 5], [8, 1, 4, 6]))
```

If you want to pass a list as an argument to the function, rather than a list inside a tuple, just remove the `*` (which unpacks the list).

If you want to apply it to the entire array in one statement without defining a function:

```
a3 = [list(set(itertools.chain(*row))) for row in a2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatting a tuple of lists:

```
from itertools import chain
new_tuple = [ list(set(chain.from_iterable(each_tuple))) for each_tuple in main_tuple_coll ]
```

I think this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Flatten list combinations

```
comb = []
for line in a2[:3]:
    l = list(set([x for y in line for x in y]))
    comb.append(l)
comb
```

[out]

```
[[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with:

```
arr = list(itertools.combinations(a,3))
for i in arr:
    arrnew[i].append(list(set().union(arr[i][:3])))
```

Is that `i` is not the index of the item but the item in the list itself.

What you need is:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,4,7],[8,2,5],[8,1,4,6],[8,1,3,5],
              [2,3,4,7],[2,5,6,7],[2,3,4,6,8],[1,3,5,6,7]])
arrnew = []

for item in itertools.combinations(a,3):
    arrnew.append(list(set().union(*item)))
```

The result `arrnew` contains 56 items. Some are equal but none contain duplicates.

I would suggest using `sorted` rather than `list` to ensure that the items in each combined list are in ascending order.